# Connecting to NFS share hangs with Manjara/Arch

Tags: arch-linux, freebsd, nfs, manjaro, nfsv4

I've setup a fresh FreeBSD 12.1 server with NFS that I'm trying to connect Manjaro to.

*I wont go into too much detail here, as it's working fine with other clients

(OS X machines, with cmd+k `nfs://host/share`, connect without a hitch)*.

For whatever reason, Manjaro cannot, or will not, connect/mount the NFS share.
I've temporarily set a test share that's readonly and allowed by all.

```
/tank/dummy -ro -alldirs
```

From the Manjaro side, I've done:

```
% rpcinfo -p nfsshare
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    4     7    111  portmapper
    100000    3     7    111  portmapper
    100000    2     7    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp    798  mountd
    100005    3   udp    798  mountd
    100005    1   tcp    798  mountd
    100005    3   tcp    798  mountd
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
```

...and

```
% showmount -e nfsshare
/tank/dummy (everyone)
```

As I can connect with other machines, I know it's not a firewall issue, but...

```
% telnet dummy 2049
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to nfsshare.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Just issuing a mount command hangs for quite some time, before timing out:

```
% sudo mount -t nfs4 nfsshare:/tank/dummy /mnt/nfs/dummy
```

Adding the mount to `/etc/fstab`, so I can mount as my user:

```
nfsshare:/trunk/dummy     /mnt/nfs/dummy  nfs4    rw,relatime,user,noauto 0 0
```

I get the same hang as before:

```
% mount /mnt/dummy
```

My `id:gid` are the same on both the FreeBSD, serving NFS, as they are on my Manjaro client.
I did run across the Arch wiki page stating that using an IP may cause it to hang, and since this is just a private network, I just added an entry within `/etc/host`.

I'm at a loss on how to get this working with Manjaro, is there something simple I'm just missing here?

*(I've tried both just NFS and v4, to no avail)*

---

```
% sudo mount -vvv -t nfs -o vers=4 nfsshare:/tank/dummy /mnt/dummy
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon May 25 15:30:31 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=X.X.X.X,clientaddr=X.X.X.X'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

^^ hangs here *(exits with 32)*

```
% sudo mount -vvv -t nfs -o vers=3 nfsshare:/tank/dummy /mnt/dummy
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon May 25 15:29:32 2020
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/remote-fs.target.wants/rpc-statd.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/rpc-statd.service.
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3,addr=X.X.X.X'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying X.X.X.X prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying X.X.X.X prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 798
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

^^ and here *(exits with 32)*

Comment: adding -v (verbose) to your mount command from the command line may shine some line on what it's trying to do and why it's hanging.  What is the output?

Comment: @L.Ray, added verbose outputs to the bottom, thx.

Comment: Are you saying you're able telnet from the client to port 2049 of the server without issue, or are you just illustrating that it works from a different client?  When you type "exportfs" on the NFS server, do you see the filesystem exported to the correct IP address?   Do you have a firewall running on the client that won't connect?  Is there anything in /var/log/messages concerning why you can't connect?

Comment: The `telnet` was just to rule out anything blocking the client from connecting to the NFS server/port. I don't have an `exportfs` on FreeBSD. Since I can mount the share using a MacBook, It seems more like an issue with my Manjaro box.